# Login from High-Trusted SharePoint Provider Hosted App using FBA

Tags: provider-hosted-app, oauth

I created a sharepoint provider hosted app (high-trusted app) that uses an asp .net membership provider customized to use an external service.
I configured the sharepoint web application to use the same membership provider.
This FBA system runs, without problems, on the two system.

So, I want that the users can log in on he app, and then it, using a clientContext, can do CRUD operation in sharepoint web application.

I use this method to create a clientContext:

```
TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithClaimsIdentity
```

and into this method i create a server-to-server token that contains in particular the following claims:

```
//Actor claims
Issuer = 3172d9fb-4fd2-afbc-4d5c-82f2755aa934@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376
nameid = 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376
trustedfordelegation = true

//Outer claims
Issuer = 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376
nii = urn:office:idp:forms:customizedmembershipprovider
nameid = i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername
nid = i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername
identityprovider = forms
```

If I use the actor token the context is created, but I operate by the app and not using the user permissions.
If I send the complete token (outer + actor), sharepoint return a 401 error.
I opened the logs and found the following information

```
SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler: Issuer name in token '3172d9fb-4fd2-afbc-4d5c-82f2755aa934@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376' matches the registered issuer name for trusted sts 'High Trust App'.
SPIdentityClaims: Couldn't find claim of type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2012/01/nameidissuer'
SPIdentityClaims: Couldn't find claim of type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2012/01/upn'
SPIdentityClaims: Couldn't find claim of type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2012/01/smtp'
SPIdentityClaims: Couldn't find claim of type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2012/01/sip'
SPIncomingIdentityHandler: This is not an app-only token, returning.
SPSecurityTokenServiceManager!GetProviderByName: Searching Trusted Security Token Issuers for input High Trust App
SPJsonWebSecurityBaseTokenHandler: ValidateActorIsSelfIssuer! Issuer 'High Trust App' is not self issuer.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Audience:00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/appdomain:80@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Not Valid Before:03/05/2014 17:04:45, Valid To:03/05/2014 17:14:45.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Issuer:00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['nii':'urn:office:idp:forms:customizedmembershipprovider'].
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['nameid':'i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername'].
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['nid':'i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername'].
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['identityprovider':'forms'].
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Audience:00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/appdomain:80@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Not Valid Before:03/05/2014 17:04:45, Valid To:01/29/2016 03:44:45.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Issuer:3172d9fb-4fd2-afbc-4d5c-82f2755aa934@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376.
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['nameid':'00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376'].
SPSecurityTokenExtensions: Claim['trustedfordelegation':'true'].
Entering monitored scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Parent [S2S] Getting token from STS and setting Thread Identity
Leaving Monitored Scope (Getting Site Subscription Id). Execution Time=0.0468
Entering monitored scope (Reading token from Cache using token signature). Parent [S2S] Getting token from STS and setting Thread Identity
Leaving Monitored Scope (Reading token from Cache using token signature). Execution Time=1.0524
EncodeProviderUserKey couldn't encode provider user key for input [originalIssuerType:'Unknown'] [originalIssuerIdentifier:'office:idp:forms:customizedmembershipprovider'] [providerUserKeyValue:'i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername']
Leaving Monitored Scope (Application Authentication Pipeline). Execution Time=3.9147
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Failed to authenticate request, unknown error. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetProviderName(String fullName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.IsEncodedClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TryBuildCacheKey(IClaimsIdentity userIdentity, String& cacheKey)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TrySignInUserFromCache(SPIncomingTokenContext tokenContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TrySignInUsi...
...ngUserLoginTokenCache(SPIncomingTokenContext tokenContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.ConstructIClaimsPrincipalAndSetThreadIdentity(HttpApplication httpApplication, HttpContext httpContext, SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
Application error when access /_vti_bin/client.svc, Error=Value cannot be null.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetProviderName(String fullName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.IsEncodedClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TryBuildCacheKey(IClaimsIdentity userIdentity, String& cacheKey)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TrySignInUserFromCache(SPIncomingTokenContext tokenContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.TrySignInUsingUserLoginTokenCache(SPIncomingTokenContext tokenContext)     at Microsoft...
....SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.ConstructIClaimsPrincipalAndSetThreadIdentity(HttpApplication httpApplication, HttpContext httpContext, SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPApplicationAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://appdomain:80/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery)). Execution Time=5.5938
SPOAuthHttpChallenge: Setting WWW-Authenticate header to:Bearer realm="805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376",client_id="00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",trusted_issuers="3172d9fb-4fd2-afbc-4d5c-82f2755aa934@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376"
```

In the log I can see that it doesn't found any IdentityClaims, but I passed the identityprovider (forms) and the provider name.

If in the Management Shell run the **Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig** command, it returns:

```
SecurityTokenServicePublicUrlSuffix         : /_vti_bin/spsecuritytokenserviceactive.svc
SecurityTokenServiceMetadataPublicUrlSuffix : /_vti_bin/spsecuritytokenserviceactive.svc/mex
LocalLoginProvider                          : SPLocalLoginProvider Name=SharePoint
TrustedLoginProviderNames                   : {}
TrustedLoginProviders                       : {}
TrustedAccessProviders                      : {}
TrustedSecurityTokenServices                : {High Trust App}
AuthenticationPipelineClaimMappingRules     : {WindowsMappingRule}
AllowMetadataOverHttp                       : False
UseSessionCookies                           : False
WindowsTokenLifetime                        : 10:00:00
FormsTokenLifetime                          : 10:00:00
CookieLifetime                              : 5.00:00:00
ServiceTokenLifetime                        : 10:00:00
MaxLogonTokenCacheItems                     : 250
MaxLogonTokenOptimisticCacheItems           : 100000
LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow             : 00:10:00
MaxServiceTokenCacheItems                   : 250
MaxServiceTokenOptimisticCacheItems         : 100000
ServiceTokenCacheExpirationWindow           : 00:10:00
ApplicationTokenLifetime                    : 1.12:00:00
AuthenticatorTokenLifetime                  : 1.12:00:00
MinApplicationTokenCacheItems               : 250
MaxApplicationTokenCacheItems               : 100000
ApplicationTokenCacheExpirationWindow       : 00:10:00
LoopbackTokenLifetime                       : 10:00:00
AllowOAuthOverHttp                          : True
CookieValueHandlerType                      : Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSessionSecurityTokenCookieValue
NameIdentifier                              : 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@805beba8-f6b4-1234-badf-7f2807cf7376
PidEnabled                                  : True
HybridStsSelectionEnabled                   : True
Name                                        : SecurityTokenServiceManager
TypeName                                    : Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager
DisplayName                                 : SecurityTokenServiceManager
Id                                          : 772171b3-a123-6543-aa22-f6b3b219af21
Status                                      : Online
Parent                                      : SPSecurityTokenService Name=SecurityTokenService
Version                                     : 2375881
Properties                                  : {}
Farm                                        : SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
UpgradedPersistedProperties                 : {}
CanSelectForBackup                          : True
DiskSizeRequired                            : 0
CanSelectForRestore                         : True
CanRenameOnRestore                          : False
```

I want highlight this three configuration settings

> **TrustedLoginProviderNames: {}**
>
> **TrustedLoginProviders    : {}**
>
> **TrustedAccessProviders   : {}**

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you figured out?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The import error is towards the bottom "EncodeProviderUserKey couldn't encode provider user key for input [originalIssuerType:'Unknown'] [originalIssuerIdentifier:'office:idp:forms:customizedmembershipprovider'] [providerUserKeyValue:'i:0#.f|customizedmembershipprovider|testusername']
"

First upgrade to August 2014 CU or higher

Second make sure your claims provider implements  SupportsUserKey.

I wrote a blog post on my journey here http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/02/on-premises-claims-authenticated-sharepoint-2013-and-hybrid-apps-hosted-in-azure/